# why is there a shadow host box when i launch my website from local host

Tags: css, sass, localhost

These is a square box appearing in my webpage when I launch it from local host in chrome. But the box seems to disappear when I open in normally and in incognito mode.

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

I want to know where the box in coming from. I have tried to delete the cache and history of my browser but nothing changed.

Comment: I found a way to make the box invisible by removing the styles. But I still don't understand why there is <div id="forest-ext-shadow-host">. . .</div> when I inspect  the code.

Comment: Looks like (your) JavaScript code is attaching a shadowRoot to that element. Could also be an extension that adds it, given the id ``forest-ext-shadow-dom``

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman I do have an extension called forest. I will try after removing it.

Answer (score 3):

By removing the "Loom" Chrome extension, I was able to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

you can solve this problem after removing forest extension. it is creating some internal changes in code of website. so try after uninstalling it.